# Can we Use Bootstrap Theme For a WordPress Website?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, themes

i want to ask Can we use bootstrap theme for a WordPress website did it work well in WordPress website?

Thanks

Comment: yes ofcourse, you can use.

Comment: Yes, use one of those https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+wp+starter+theme

Answer (score 0):

If the Bootstrap theme is also a WordPress theme, it is possible. If not, you need to create a WordPress theme from it first.